# Jquery selector to find out count of non empty inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the below HTML DOM

```
      <div id="container>
        <p data-bind="visible:ShowPostCode()">
    <label class="field-label" for="postcode">Postcode</label>
    <input id="txtPostCode" data-bind="value:PostCode, valueUpdate: &quot;afterkeydown&quot;" class="field-stretch" type="text">
    </p>

     <p data-bind="visible:ShowDateOfBirth()">
    <label class="field-label" for="dateofbirth">Date of birth</label>
    <input data-bind="value:DateOfBirth, valueUpdate: &quot;afterkeydown&quot;" class="field-stretch" type="text">
    </p>

             <p style="display: none;" data-bind="visible:ShowtelephoneNumber()">
    <label class="field-label" for="telephoneNumber">Telephone number</label>
    <input data-bind="value:DrivingLicenceNumber, valueUpdate: &quot;afterkeydown&quot;" class="field-stretch" type="text">
    </p>
   </div>
```

I would like to get the no of non-empty input boxes.

This is what i tried

```
$('#container input[type="text"][value!=""]').length
```

or

```
$('#container input[type="text"]').filter('input[value!=""]').length
```

even when i input some values it is always showing as zero . what is wrong with these selectors i tried and why it is not working?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can pass in a filter function rather than a selector:

```
$('#container input[type="text"]').filter(function () {
    return !!this.value;
}).length;
```

Comment: @A1rPun No because value is a string. `!!'0' === true`

Comment: @A1rPun The value property of a text input is always a string.

Comment: Why `$('#container input[type="text"][value!=""]')` is not working? any reason?

Comment: Murali check Antons reply below

Answer (score 14):

The attribute value will always be the default value so you must filter through the input boxes and check the value like this code below

```
$('#container input[type="text"]').filter(function () {
    return this.value.length > 0
}).length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CMjLn/1/)

Comment: Thanks it is working , still not sure why this is not working can any one explain what is happening when i use this selector ? $('#container input[type="text"][value!=""]').length

Comment: Thats because [value] will search for the default value attribute. The value attribute doesn't change when you type in the input boxes @Bumble